# How to fix "A lint plugin threw an exception - dart(custom_lint_get_lint_fail)"?

Tags: dart, riverpod

I have this lint error.

> A lint plugin threw an exception - dart(custom_lint_get_lint_fail)

The error occurs at the first line in the following code.

```dart
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

/// ...
```

However, If I remove the first line, the same error occurs in the second line (`import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';`).

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What version of riverpod do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the [Riverpod 2.3.0](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod/) release (`riverpod_lint: ^1.0.1`)

See more:

[[lint] A lint plugin threw an exception - dart(custom_lint_get_lint_fail) #2168](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/discussions/2168)